# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function idn_to_ascii() on PHP 7.2.13

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.2

I'm trying to use [idn_to_ascii()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii.php)  on PHP version 7.2.13 but I'm receiving:

`Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function idn_to_ascii()`

I don't have the PECL intl extension installed, but according to the [top user contributed note on the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii.php#108900), I don't need it:

`"...if you have >=5.4 you will not require the PECL extensions. "`

Is the user note wrong? If not, then what am I doing wrong?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php, it’s *bundled*, but must be explicitly *enabled* at installation time.

Comment: You'll probably have to install php7-intl. The number may change based on your system and the packages available.

Comment: @deceze Thanks - so the user note is wrong?

Comment: No, it’s correct, you do not require the PECL extension. That doesn’t mean it’s automagically available always.

Comment: @deceze OK, thanks. I understand that I need the intl extension, which is bundled (and therefore not a PECL extension, but an extension nonetheless). But am I wrong in thinking that should be made clear somewhere? WHERE exactly is the information telling me I need to enable the intl extension?

Comment: @deceze oh, duhh.. I think I realize now - the documentation for it is within the [International](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) subcategory of functions, and it explains it nicely there. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to activate the "intl" php module.

You can do it by cPanel Select PHP Version configuration by checking the "intl" module and save.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Ubuntu, you can run the bellow command to install the intl module depending on your PHP version-

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

Comment: I'd agree, but this might only be 1/3rd of the answer; PHP 7.2 is soon irrelevant anyway.

Comment: just replace 7.0 partion to 8.0 or 8.1

Answer (score 0):

It depends on PECL [`idn`](https://pecl.php.net/package/idn/0.2.0) module and the [`libidn`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/) library. There's just no need to install `php-intl` from PECL - as `php7.0-intl` provides it. Run `php -m` to see which modules had been loaded.

On RHEL one could install all of them with:

```
sudo dnf install php72-php-intl.x86_64 libidn2.x86_64 
sudo pecl install idn
```